# Having problem with pgsql2shp function - get postgis_version() function not found error

Tags: postgis, pgsql2shp

I try to use `pgsql2shp` postgis function to export a table from another schema to `.shp` format.
Base on [this link](https://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg), I run following code

```
pgsql2shp -f "c:/path/to/export/file" -h localhost -u <username> -P <password> atlas country.parcel
```

I created a `country` schema and then added `postgis` extension to it but I get this error

```
ERROR:  function postgis_version() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT postgis_version()
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm pretty sure that I've added `postgis` extension to it. I followed some solutions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407622/postgis-not-available-for-all-postgres-users) but they didn't work. I think it is not related to `search_path` as it's mentioned in above solution.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I listed database extensions by `\dx` sql command, I realized that the `postgis` extension has been set on the `country` schema so I changed it to `public` schema. After this change, I restarted `postgresql` service and the problem was resolved.

Change extension schema target by

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis SET SCHEMA public;
```

Final result is something as follow

[image]